# How can I call a method as background worker by adding it into Startup in .netcore 2.1?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a simple logging system by using Nest and C#. I have a log producer for collecting logs inside of blockingcollection. Also I have a consumer. But I stumpled upon with an issue. How can I use my comsumer in startup or is there any way to create background servise which was listening queue of blockingcollection? What is best practice of it? I am confusing how to call AsyncConsumer or consumer when application startup.

```
 public class SimpleLog
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string LogDate { get; set; }
        public string Sessionid { get; set; }
        public string Userid { get; set; }
        public string Correlationid { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string UrlQueryString { get; set; }
        public string UrlPath { get; set; }
        public string UrlMethod { get; set; }
        public string Environment { get; set; }
        public string IndexName { get; set; }
        public string IndexType { get; set; }

    }
    public class QuickLog
    {
        private static BlockingCollection<SimpleLog> data = new BlockingCollection<SimpleLog>();


        public static void Producer(SimpleLog pageviewLog)
        {
            data.TryAdd(pageviewLog, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }

        public static void Consumer()
        {
            var _client = ElasticConfig.GetClient();
            var logs = new List<SimpleLog>();

            foreach (var item in data.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                logs.Add(item);
            }

            if (logs == null && logs.Count <= 0)
                return;
            var log = logs.FirstOrDefault();

            var response = _client.IndexMany(logs, log.IndexName, log.IndexType);

            if (!response.IsValid)
                throw response.OriginalException;


        }

        public async Task AsyncConsumer()
        {
            var _client = ElasticConfig.GetClient();
            var logs = new List<SimpleLog>();

            foreach (var item in data.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                logs.Add(item);
            }
            if (logs == null && logs.Count <= 0)
                return;
            var log = logs.FirstOrDefault();
            var response = await _client.IndexManyAsync(logs, log.IndexName, log.IndexType).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (!response.IsValid)
                throw response.OriginalException;

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    public static class ElasticConfig
    {
        private static IElasticClient _client;
        static ElasticConfig()
        {
            var esurl = LogSettings.Url;
            string[] urls = esurl.Split(',');
            var nodes = new Uri[2];

            for (int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i++)
            {
                nodes.SetValue(new Uri(urls[i]), i);
            }

            var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(nodes);
            var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool).RequestTimeout(
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
                .PingTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
                .MaxRetryTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
                .MaxDeadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
                .DeadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).DisablePing()
                                .SniffOnConnectionFault(false)
                                .SniffOnStartup(false)
                                .SniffLifeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            _client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
        }
        public static IElasticClient GetClient()
        {
            return _client;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure Consumer/Producer is the right definition for your use case. It's difficult to understand what those methods do since method names do not correspond to the behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how many times and which method exactly you want to call. If you want to run some asynchronous background jobs you can use IHostedService. You will need to install  [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting) NuGet package or [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Usage:

Add this line to your `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddHostedService<LogBackgroundService>(); //service is instance of IServiceCollection
```

And this is the implementation of your background service:

```
public class LogBackgroundService : IHostedService
{

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await QuickLog.AsyncConsumer(); // or whatever you want to call           
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Behavior:

It will run once(but IHostedService still will be running. If you want to reduce resource consumption just call `StopAsync()` when it's done). If you want to run something in a loop, you can implement this:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    await QuickLog.AsyncConsumer();
    await Task.Delay(250, cancellationToken); // you can add this if you want to throttle 
}
```

PS. If you need to run multiple IHostedServices in your application without blocking each other you will need to wrap your methods into `Tasks`:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task.Run(() =>  QuickLog.AsyncConsumer(), cancellationToken);
 }
```

Comment: @Olegl Thank you for your great help. But I want to learn something. is it looping? AsyncConsumer needs to run without stop may be it needs a while(true). AsyncConsumer  needs a new class which is implemented from  internal class NewQuickLog: BackgroundService
    {

Answer (score 3):

IHostedService is solution for you.

You can crate new class and inherit from this class https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/a7dd5064d9dcf35b6eae1a7953d615e3

Then your new class will be something like this

```
public class LogService : HostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public LogBackgroundService (IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await new QuickLog().AsyncConsumer(cancellationToken); 
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally update your Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, LogService>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your great help. But I want to learn something. is it looping? AsyncConsumer  needs a new class which is implemented from  internal class NewQuickLog: BackgroundService
    {